# I require some assistance with this C++ algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to solve an algorithm problem but I cannot find the solution...

The task is to output the lowest number of steps needed to reach a certain configuration of lamps.

There are two rows of lamps and N < 10000 columns, like so:

```
11011
11011
```

or

```
11101101111000101010
01111101100000010100
```

These lamps can be "on" (1) or "off" (0).

Starting from all off (0), the program has to output the number of steps it took to reach the desired configuration.

A step can be:

- toggle one lamp
- toggle two lamps, one above the other (in the same column)
- toggle n consecutive lamps in the same row, it can be the whole row, it can be only two (or one as explained above)

I figured that the algorithm should simply count the number of steps it takes to switch the lights completely off, and that would be the same as in the "right" order. Also my guess was to try and find "holes", i.e. sequences of more than one lamp with the same state, and then switching those. But it gets complicated since there are two rows...

However I was completely lost after that point and I require some help...

Comment: Please define what a step is.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting that, I did now

Comment: So, from what I understand, a move is one of the following: Toggling all the lamps in one row, or toggling two lamps, one above the other.  Is this correct?

Comment: Your specification is still a bit vague: Does “switching consecutive lamps” mean **all** lamps in a row/column (as @AJMansfield suggested), or exactly **two** adjacent lamps, or **one or more** adjacent lamps, or **two or more** adjacent lamps?

Comment: I explained what a step is in more detail, hopefully that will cover it.

Comment: @AberKled Is O(n^2) solution acceptable?

Comment: Since `N < 10 000`, I think that it is. I'm generally looking for ideas, because I'm lost.

Comment: You have to reach the second configuration, and you are allowed to change both. I'm correct ?

Comment: @CapelliC I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. You have to reach the inputted configuration from a blank configuration (all 0).

Comment: thanks, I didn't read with sufficient attention...

Comment: So let's see if I'm understanding this correctly.  In your first example, the minimum number of steps would be 4, because you can toggle the groups of two 1's for the first row (2 steps) and then for the second row (2 steps), or alternatively toggle columns 1, 2, 4, and 5.  However, if the first row were all 1's, then the minimum number of steps would be 3 because you could toggle the entire row (1 step), and then the two groups of two 1's on the second row.  Is that right?

Comment: @AberKled If it is a programming contest problem, please share a link to it. I'll implement my solution posted below.

Comment: @pjs you only need 3 moves: toggle col 3, toggle complete row 1 then toggle complete row 2.

Comment: @pkacprzak Yes, it is from a 2006 contest in my country. [link](http://hsin.hr/zup06/zadaci/pas_c_cpp/druga/zadaci.pdf), but I doubt it will be useful to you since you since it's not on English. This task is "lampice", #3.

Comment: Really? People get their question upvoted by copy/pasting programming challenges from competitions? Even without an attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: Read the question again. I obviously attempted to solve the problem but I couldn't so I asked. And it was downvoted mostly at first.

Comment: What was the outcome of this?

Answer (score 7):

## Edit:

OP has posted recently a link to the original problem statement, and it turned out that you are allowed to switch lights back and forth. My below solution works only if you are allowed to switch lights only on.

### Definitions

Let's define:

`U[i] := i-th light in the upper row.`

`L[i] := i-th light in the lower row.`

`A[i][j] := subconfiguration of the input configuration where you have i lamps in the upper row and j lamps in the lower row.`

For example, if the starting state is:

```
11101101111000101010
01111101100000010100
```

Then `A[5][2]` is:

```
11101
01
```

Secondly, let's define:

`f(i, j) := minimum number of moves to switch all lights off in A[i][j]`

You are interested in computing `f(n, n)`

In addition, let's define:

`RU[i] := maximal consecutive run of 1's in the upper row ending in the i-th position.`

`RL[i] := maximal consecutive run of 1's in the lower row ending in the i-th position.`

For example, if the starting state is:

```
11101101111000101010
01111101100000010100
```

Then `RU[1] = 1`, `RU[3] = 3`, `RU[4] = 0`

You can compute both RU and RL from left to right in `O(n)` time.

### Observations

First, observe that if `A[i][j]` has `k_1` zeros at the end of the upper row and `k_2` zeros at the end of the lower row, then `f(i, j) = f(i - k_1, j - k_2)` because the last `k_1` and `k_2` lights are already switched off.

### Recurrence relation

Observe, that if you want to compute `f(i, j)` there are 3 cases:

1. Switch off maximal consecutive run of 1's in the upper row in one move
2. Switch off maximal consecutive run of 1's in the lower row in one move
3. If i = j and lights U[i] and L[j] are switched on, then you can switch both off in one move

Of course, the base case is `f(0, 0)` and it requires 0 moves.

Then in order to compute `f(i, j)`:

```
if U[i] is switched off: //skip zeros at the end of the upper row
   compute f(i - 1, j)
else if L[j] is switched off: //skip zeros at the end of the lower row
   compute f(i, j - 1)
else           
   if i == j // U[i] and L[j] are switched on because we skipped zeros at the end
       f(i, j) = min(f(i - RU[i], j), f(i, j - RL[j]), f(i - 1, j - 1)) + 1

   else:
       f(i, j) = min(f(i - RU[i], j), f(i, j - RL[j])) + 1
```

### Memoization

To avoid computing `f` for the same `i` and `j` many times during recursive calls, just store the results of already computed `f` in a hash table and return them in `O(1)` rather than compute again.

### Runtime

The simple upper bound is of course `O(n^2)` because there are at most `O(n^2)` subproblems.

Comment: There are 2^2n configurations. How did you get O(n^2) ?

Comment: I didn't count configurations. I counted subproblems i.e. f(i, j) for all 1 <= i, j <= n

Comment: Got it. Good solution, but the proof of optimality looks incomplete. Why we cannot reach better result if we switch in a different order?

Well, I know the answer - that is because the operations are commutative and we can always move the operations that touch the rightmost lamps to the end

Comment: I started examining the solution, but just to ask this first: are you using dynamic programming (or recursion) to solve this?

Comment: @AberKled Yes, this is a recursive solution with memoization

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit If you look closely on your input, you'll see that 11 is not the minimum.

Comment: 8 steps is the minimum afaik

Comment: @sehe: my solution currently does it in 7, but can't post until question is reopened :)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I have long voted to reopen :) A power failure killed my own attempt. I might rewrite it if it gets reopened

Comment: This solution is too complex. It can be solved with a single iteration.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>This is a sweet case for `std::bitset`!</strike>

Okay, since I grossly misunderstood the first time, I decided to do a simple heuristic.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The solver with a single, simple heuristic:
//
// If there's a hole in a range for row1 where row2 is to have a `1`, we might
// benefit from toggling both rows in advance, because it might result in a
// longer stretch to toggle in the first row
//
// An obvious improvement would to be to try with rows swapped as well.
//
// (As a bonus, all solutions are verified)
int solve(std::ostream& os, bitset row1, bitset row2)
{
    auto candidates = row2 & ~row1;

    int best_count = row1.size() + 1; // or INT_MAX or similar
    bitset best_edits;

    for (auto const& edits : combinations(candidates))
    {
        std::stringstream steps_stream;
        int count = emit_steps(steps_stream, row1, row2, edits);

        assert(verify(steps_stream, row1, row2, false));

        if (count < best_count)
        {
            best_edits = edits;
            best_count = count;
        }
    }

    return emit_steps(os, row1, row2, best_edits);
}
```

This `solve(...)` method now emits a script of steps, that gets verified with (a modified version of) the interpreter from my original answer:

```
// test driver reading the target configuration from stdin
// and displaying the 'best found' solution with intermediate steps
int main()
{
    bitset row1, row2;

    if (std::cin >> row1 >> row2)
    {
        std::stringstream steps;
        int number = solve(steps, row1, row2);

        std::cout << "Best candidate found results in " << number << " steps:\n";
        verify(steps, row1, row2, true);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Best candidate found results in 8 steps:
Start verify
after 'toggle both 2':
  row1: 00000000000000000000000000000100
  row2: 00000000000000000000000000000100
after 'toggle both 4':
  row1: 00000000000000000000000000010100
  row2: 00000000000000000000000000010100
after 'toggle first from 1 through 5':
  row1: 00000000000000000000000000101010
  row2: 00000000000000000000000000010100
after 'toggle first from 9 through 12':
  row1: 00000000000000000001111000101010
  row2: 00000000000000000000000000010100
after 'toggle first from 14 through 15':
  row1: 00000000000000001101111000101010
  row2: 00000000000000000000000000010100
after 'toggle first from 17 through 19':
  row1: 00000000000011101101111000101010
  row2: 00000000000000000000000000010100
after 'toggle second from 11 through 12':
  row1: 00000000000011101101111000101010
  row2: 00000000000000000001100000010100
after 'toggle second from 14 through 18':
  row1: 00000000000011101101111000101010
  row2: 00000000000001111101100000010100
Done
```

### Full demo program: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1a4c141b7dd9ae0077e2164034114e64-20ff61d2a9967611ab15166bb37333d1)**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using bitset = boost::dynamic_bitset<>;

// bitset helpers
int count_ranges(bitset const& bs);
std::vector<bitset> combinations(bitset const& bs);

// generate the steps script
int emit_apply_both (std::ostream& os, bitset const& edits);
int emit_toggles    (std::ostream& os, bitset const& row, std::string const& row_name);
int emit_steps      (std::ostream& os, bitset const& row1, bitset const& row2, bitset const& edits);

// applies a steps script from scratch and verifies the result 
// (optionally tracing all steps along the way)
bool verify(std::istream& is, bitset const& target1, bitset const& target2, bool verbose);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The solver with a single, simple heuristic:
//
// If there's a hole in a range for row1 where row2 is to have a `1`, we might
// benefit from toggling both rows in advance, because it might result in a
// longer stretch to toggle in the first row
//
// An obvious improvement would to be to try with rows swapped as well.
//
// (As a bonus, all solutions are verified)
int solve(std::ostream& os, bitset row1, bitset row2)
{
    auto candidates = row2 & ~row1;

    int best_count = row1.size() + 1; // or INT_MAX or similar
    bitset best_edits;

    for (auto const& edits : combinations(candidates))
    {
        std::stringstream steps_stream;
        int count = emit_steps(steps_stream, row1, row2, edits);

        assert(verify(steps_stream, row1, row2, false));

        if (count < best_count)
        {
            best_edits = edits;
            best_count = count;
        }
    }

    return emit_steps(os, row1, row2, best_edits);
}

// test driver reading the target configuration from stdin
// and displaying the 'best found' solution with intermediate steps
int main()
{
    bitset row1, row2;

    if (std::cin >> row1 >> row2)
    {
        std::stringstream steps;
        int number = solve(steps, row1, row2);

        std::cout << "Best candidate found results in " << number << " steps:\n";
        verify(steps, row1, row2, true);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// details, helpers
int count_ranges(bitset const& bs)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (auto bit=bs.find_first(); bit!=bitset::npos; bit=bs.find_next(bit))
    {
        do ++bit; while (bit<=bs.size() && bs[bit]);
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

std::vector<bitset> combinations(bitset const& bs)
{
    bitset accum(bs.size());
    std::vector<bitset> result;
    std::function<void(size_t bit)> recurse = [&](size_t bit) mutable 
    {
        if (bit == bitset::npos)
            result.push_back(accum);
        else
        {
            accum.flip(bit); recurse(bs.find_next(bit));
            accum.flip(bit); recurse(bs.find_next(bit));
        }
    };

    return recurse(bs.find_first()), result;
}

int emit_toggles(std::ostream& os, bitset const& row, std::string const& row_name)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (auto start=row.find_first(); start!=bitset::npos; start=row.find_next(start))
    {
        auto end = start;
        do ++end; while (end<row.size() && row[end]);
        if (start+1 == end)
            os << "toggle " << row_name << " " << start << "\n";
        else
            os << "toggle " << row_name << " from " << start << " through " << (end-1) << "\n";
        count += 1;
        start = end;
    }
    return count;
}

int emit_apply_both(std::ostream& os, bitset const& edits)
{
    for (auto bit=edits.find_first(); bit!=bitset::npos; bit=edits.find_next(bit))
        os << "toggle both " << bit << "\n";
    return edits.count();
}

int emit_steps(std::ostream& os, bitset const& row1, bitset const& row2, bitset const& edits)
{
    auto count = emit_apply_both(os, edits);
    count     += emit_toggles   (os, row1 ^ edits, "first");
    count     += emit_toggles   (os, row2 ^ edits, "second");
    return count;
}

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
template <typename Lambda> struct WrapAction {
    template <typename...> struct result { typedef void type; };
    template <typename... T> void operator()(T&&... t) const { _ll(std::forward<T>(t)...); }

    WrapAction(Lambda&& ll) : _ll(std::forward<Lambda>(ll)) { }
  private:
    mutable Lambda _ll;
};

template <typename Lambda> WrapAction<Lambda> make_action(Lambda&& ll) { return { std::forward<Lambda>(ll) }; }

bool verify(std::istream& is, bitset const& target1, bitset const& target2, bool verbose)
{
    bitset row1(target1.size()), row2(target2.size());
    if (verbose) std::cout << "Start verify\n";

    auto toggle1 = make_action([&](int i) mutable { row1.flip(i); });
    auto toggle2 = make_action([&](int i) mutable { row2.flip(i); });
    auto both    = make_action([&](int i) mutable { toggle1(i); toggle2(i); });
    auto range1  = make_action([&](int i1, int i2) mutable { while (i2>=i1) toggle1(i2--); });
    auto range2  = make_action([&](int i1, int i2) mutable { while (i2>=i1) toggle2(i2--); });

    // for statement tracing:
    typedef boost::spirit::istream_iterator It;
    auto trace = make_action([&](boost::iterator_range<It> const& raw_iterators) mutable {
                if (verbose) {
                    std::cout << "after '" << std::string(raw_iterators.begin(), raw_iterators.end()) << "':\n";
                    std::cout << "  row1:\t" << row1 << "\n" << "  row2:\t" << row2 << "\n"; 
                }
            });

    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
    using phx::bind;
    using phx::construct;

    is.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
    It f(is), l;
    bool ok = phrase_parse(f, l,
            - raw [  
                lit("toggle") >> ("both" >> int_)                                       [ bind(both, _1)       ]
              | lit("toggle") >> lit("first")  >> ("from" >> int_ >> "through" >> int_) [ bind(range1, _1, _2) ]
              | lit("toggle") >> lit("second") >> ("from" >> int_ >> "through" >> int_) [ bind(range2, _1, _2) ]
              | "toggle"      >> lit("first")  >> (int_)                                [ bind(toggle1,  _1)   ]
              | "toggle"      >> lit("second") >> (int_)                                [ bind(toggle2,  _1)   ]
              | eps(false)
             ] [ bind(trace, _1) ] % eol,
            blank);

    if (verbose)
    {
        if (ok)     std::cout << "Done\n";
        else        std::cout << "Failed\n";
        if (f != l) std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }

    return ok && (f==l) && (row1==target1) && (row2==target2);
}
```

Comment: I seem to have misunderstand the goal of the program. Hmm. Oh well. That question would be overly localized anyways, I fear

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit So I've **[re-instated my brute-force solve](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1a4c141b7dd9ae0077e2164034114e64-20ff61d2a9967611ab15166bb37333d1)** for fun. I even managed to redo both the bugs I had written the first time around :) (I don't presume this is an optimal solution, as indicated in the comments. However, it **is** a solution that actually verifies the results from the actual steps. It might be a useful source of inspiration for the OP)

Comment: finally my answer is posted ;)

Comment: the syntax is very odd for me.

Comment: It is solvable in 7 steps

Answer (score 2):

Finally, re-opened. Time to post my answer :)

This solution uses a single iteration `O(n+1)` and solves the 2x20 lamps example in only **7 steps**

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

const string upperInput("11101101111000101010");
const string lowerInput("01111101100000010100");
vector<bool> upper, lower;

void init()
{   // convert string rows to vector<bool> rows
    for_each(upperInput.begin(), upperInput.end(), [&](char e) { upper.push_back(e == '1'); });
    for_each(lowerInput.begin(), lowerInput.end(), [&](char e) { lower.push_back(e == '1'); });
    assert(upper.size() == lower.size());
}

void dump()
{   // output current content of vector<bool> rows
    for_each(upper.begin(), upper.end(), [] (bool b) { cout << (b ? '1' : '0'); });
    cout << endl;
    for_each(lower.begin(), lower.end(), [] (bool b) { cout << (b ? '1' : '0'); });
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

// iterate over both rows with callback
typedef function<void (const vector<bool>::iterator& itUpper, const vector<bool>::iterator& itLower)> IteratorCallback;
void iterate(const bool includeEnd, const IteratorCallback callback)
{
    for (auto itUpper = upper.begin(), itLower = lower.begin(); itUpper != upper.end(); itUpper++, itLower++)
        callback(itUpper, itLower);
    if (includeEnd)
        callback(upper.end(), lower.end());
}

int main()
{
    init();

    cout << "Initial rows data: " << endl;
    dump();

    int steps = 0;

    // a state is isolated if the state before and after holds the opposite value or is an isolated 1 at the beginning or end.
    const auto isIsolatedState = [] (const vector<bool>& source, const vector<bool>::iterator& it) {
        return (it != source.begin() && it != source.end() && *(it - 1) != *it && *(it + 1) != *it)
            || (it == source.begin() && *it && !*(it + 1))
            || (it == source.end()   && *it && !*(it - 1));
    };

    // toggle consecutive states in the given range
    const auto toggle = [] (const vector<bool>::iterator& begin, const vector<bool>::iterator& end)
    {
        for (auto it = begin; it != end; it++)
            *it = !*it;
    };

    auto upperBlockStart = upper.front() ? upper.begin() : upper.end();
    auto lowerBlockStart = lower.front() ? lower.begin() : lower.end();
    iterate(true, [&upperBlockStart, &lowerBlockStart, &steps, isIsolatedState, toggle] (const vector<bool>::iterator& itUpper, const vector<bool>::iterator& itLower) {
        // toggle columns if state in both rows is isolated
        if (itUpper != upper.end())
        {
            const int column =  itUpper - upper.begin() + 1;
            if (isIsolatedState(upper, itUpper) && isIsolatedState(lower, itLower))
            {
                cout << "#" << ++steps << ": Toggling column " << column << endl;
                toggle(itUpper, itUpper + 1);
                toggle(itLower, itLower + 1);
                dump();
            }
        }

        // keep track of blocks with 1's in upper row
        const bool upperState = itUpper != upper.end() ? *itUpper : false;
        if (upperState && upperBlockStart == upper.end())
            upperBlockStart = itUpper; // start of block of 1's in upper row
        if (!upperState && upperBlockStart != upper.end())
        {   // end of block of 1's in upper row
            const int count = itUpper - upperBlockStart;
            const int column = upperBlockStart - upper.begin() + 1;
            cout << "#" << ++steps << ": Toggling " << count << " lamp(s) in upper row starting from column " << column << endl;
            toggle(upperBlockStart, itUpper);
            upperBlockStart = upper.end();
            dump();
        }

        // keep track of blocks with 1's in lower row
        const bool lowerState = itLower != lower.end() ? *itLower : false;
        if (lowerState && *itLower && lowerBlockStart == lower.end())
            lowerBlockStart = itLower; // start of block of 1's in lower row
        if (!lowerState && lowerBlockStart != lower.end())
        {   // end of block of 1's in lower row
            const int count = itLower - lowerBlockStart;
            const int column = lowerBlockStart - lower.begin() + 1;
            cout << "#" << ++steps << ": Toggling " << count << " lamp(s) in lower row starting from column " << column << endl;
            toggle(lowerBlockStart, itLower);
            lowerBlockStart = lower.end();
            dump();
        }
    });

    cout << "Solved in " << steps << " step(s)" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[See it working on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=94dc607ba556880a0a22e229ce916bcb-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Comment: You should not flip the first column if both strings begin `"01"`, only if both strings begin `"10"`.  This slightly different problem has a solution in 7, but your algorithm answers 8.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1344ea1a8e951b5e2ab10e1ee4902ee1-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Comment: @aschepler thank you for reviewing the code! The same applies to the end: it should not flip the last column if both rows end with `10` only if both end with `01`. I updated the `isIsolatedState` lambda to take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.  O(`N`) time, single pass.  (Could even be adapted to O(1) storage, if you change the input format to accept a column at a time.)  Adding comments and proving it's correct are exercises for the reader.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::vector<bool>, 2> lamps;
    auto row_iter = lamps.begin();
    char c;
    while (std::cin.get(c) && row_iter != lamps.end()) {
        switch (c){
        case '0':
            row_iter->push_back(false);
            break;
        case '1':
            row_iter->push_back(true);
            break;
        case '\n':
            ++row_iter;
            break;
        default:
            std::cerr << "Unexpected input char "
                      << static_cast<int>(c) << std::endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    std::vector<bool>& row1 = lamps[0];
    std::vector<bool>& row2 = lamps[1];
    if (row1.size() != row2.size()) {
        std::cerr << "Rows must be the same length" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    row1.push_back(false);
    row2.push_back(false);
    unsigned int col_flips = 0;
    unsigned int changes = 0;
    bool prev1 = false, prev2 = false, both_changed = false;
    for (auto iter1=row1.cbegin(), iter2=row2.cbegin();
         iter1 != row1.cend() && iter2 != row2.cend();
         ++iter1, ++iter2) {
        unsigned int col_changes = (*iter1 != prev1);
        col_changes += (*iter2 != prev2);
        if (col_changes == 2) {
            if (both_changed) {
                changes -= 2;
                ++col_flips;
                both_changed = false;
            } else {
                changes += col_changes;
                both_changed = true;
            }
        } else {
            changes += col_changes;
            both_changed = false;
        }
        prev1 = *iter1;
        prev2 = *iter2;
    }

    std::cout << col_flips + changes/2 << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2686165f33d0e7745b3f43107fa5846b-a65d834118a7f4cf1b4d2bcafc7405de)